# How to get NHibernate to logging a file, not the console?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, log4net

If I turn on `show_sql`, then `NHibernate` logs its queries, which is what I do want to see.  However, my app is a console program and turning on `show_sql` causes the SQL to appear in the console no matter what. I do not want to see it there in the console, but only in the files.

**NOTE :** I use log4net to control logging.

Any suggestions or guidance here on this issue are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

We can use log4net and some of its appenders *(i.e. file appender like `RollingFileAppender`)* to track NHibernate *(including generated SQL)*

There is a detailed how to:

[Configure Log4Net for use with NHibernate](http://nhibernate.info/doc/howto/various/configure-log4net-for-use-with-nhibernate.html)

```
<log4net>
  <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
    <file value="c:\Logs\myLog.log" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <ConversionPattern value="[%-3d|%-4t|%-5p|%-75c] %m | %-10u %n" />
    </layout>
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <maximumFileSize value="1MB" />
    <staticLogFileName value="true" />
    <rollingStyle value="Size" />
    <maxSizeRollBackups value="2" />
  </appender>
...
```

And then declare logger

```
<logger name="NHibernate">
  <level value="WARN" />
  <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
</logger>

<logger name="NHibernate.SQL">
  <level value="DEBUG" />
  <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender" />
</logger>
```

*Note: here, we are not using configuration setting `<property name="show_sql">false</property>`. We just track with log4net*